# Launch Web Inspector/Firebug from within website?

Tags: web, web-inspector

Is it possible to launch a browser's native web inspector or developer tools via an anchor/button on a web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Its not possible. Maybe if you have an extension for that particular browser, it might be possible. Check the [chrome developer documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.html) for more details.